# How are Iterators implemented in Java?

Tags: java, iterator

Does an instance of an Iterator opened on a collection keep the whole collection in memory and access a position that increments every time next() is called?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You could always look at the source and find out :)

Comment: As regard to source reference see the code of JDK class ArrayList:http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html
where the Iterator is implemented as an inner class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation of [`Iterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) depends on the particular `Collection` it is iterating. If you look at the JDK source code, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` for example use different iterators.

Remember `Iterator` is an *interface* not a concrete class so it simply specifies a contract not an implementation.

Generally speaking iterators will (depending on the implementation) store a reference to the collection and some kind of index to mark where they're up to.

Answer (score 4):

Totally depends on the implementation, but in general (for Iterators constructed for in-memory collections), the Iterator will have a reference to the underlying collection, so yes, it will keep it in memory.

Note that this reference is most likely not a copy, which is why Iterators check for concurrent modifications to the collection they where created for.

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on the object related to the `Iterator`. Remeber that (nearly) every `Iterator` is related to an `Iterable` which we iterate over.

Each `Iterable` class can define an own `Iterator` class which, on request, returns the `next()` element.

*How* it does so deoends on which data is available instantaneously:

- It can fetch every element from a file, from a database, from a library or whatever.
- It can fetch every element from an object which is already in memory.
- and so on

In case 1 it wouldn't probably be useful to hold everything in memory, but in case 2, where we already *have* everything in memory, we could (and would) indeed query that object about the item at the next position.